# An error occurs when make any movement in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**Hello everyone these days i face a problem that make me nervous and that problem that is when i make any movement in PHPMyAdmin i get this message**

[image of error that i face is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yil5U.png)

**so if you have any suggestion please help me**

Comment: Add the image to the question, If you are nervous I am more so opening a link of unknown origin.

Comment: i add it and the link is work

Comment: this is the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/yil5U.png